# Posting to a user's wall using the POST request and graph API

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, servlets

I am new to facebook app development and i have been trying to post a simple message on the wall of the user.i have managed to get the access token .Here is the code for the POST request.I am using java servlets

```
  String data = URLEncoder.encode("access_token", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(accessToken, "UTF-8");
data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("message", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("finally", "UTF-8");
out.println("data is\n"+data);
// Send data
String u="https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed";
URL urls = new URL(u);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
wr.write(data);
wr.flush();
```

Well this code is not working and i can not post on the wall.Any suggestion as to where i might be wrong?

Comment: Not working? What do you mean? Do you get an exception or does it look ok but you just don't see the post on facebook?

Comment: Well i do not get any error.but i can not post onthe wall of the facebook user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that it's because you don't specify the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type, try this:

```
URLConnection connection = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed").openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
out.writeBytes(data);
out.flush();
out.close()
```

---

## Edit

Ok, so there are two more things that might cause this problem:

1. You also need to specify the content length.
2. You might need to read the response to make it count..

This code was tested and it works:

```
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
buffer.append("access_token").append('=').append(ACCESS_TOKEN);
buffer.append('&').append("message=").append('=').append("YO!");
String content = buffer.toString();

URLConnection connection = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed").openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(content.length()));

DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
out.writeBytes(content);
out.flush();
out.close();

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) { 
    System.out.println(inputLine);
}

in.close();
```

Comment: It worked.actually i was just checking the marty hall book on facebook and it included the two corrections that you suggested..